# Issue with creating a react application using "npx create-react-app"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I wanted to create a new react application, and I was surprised by these error messages, tried to uninstall node and npm, and reinstalled different versions.

I also tried: `npm cache clean --force`, but no result.

That's the error message :

(base) Omar:Desktop macbookpro$ npx create-react-app test-react

```
npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbookpro/.npm/_logs/2020-10-11T14_08_39_430Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

Comment: Do you use `yarn`? If yes, just try `yarn create react-app my-app`

Comment: whats in /Users/macbookpro/.npm/_logs/2020-10-11T14_08_39_430Z-debug.log  ?

Comment: Please include additional information for your question.
1. How did you install node? 
2. Which version of node did you install?
3. Do you have an active internet connection on the system you are trying to call the create-react-app on with NPX (the error indicates you may not be - or npm is not responding)
4. Consider installing/using "nvm" to manage your node installation